# Firebase Cloud Messaging onLaunch callback

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app structure is a little bit mess, but I have to add this patch first and then I'll restructure the entire logic. The thing is I first check if there's a firebase user, then if there is one I use StreamBuilder to get the current user profile from Firestore, then I have the  _firebaseMessaging.configure method because onLaunch and onResume I use this callback:

```
void _navigateToGestorResevas(Map<String, dynamic> message, User currentUser) {

    Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
            GestorScreen(user: currentUser)));
  }
```

Because I need to send the User to this screen where he fetch the message from firebase.
onResume this works fine, but onLaunch it goes to the screen and fetch the data but there are like 20 seconds where there are some kind of glitch. It switch like 20-30 times between two states where I have and no have snapshot data in this _initState func:

```
final snapshot = await _dbRef.child('mensajes').child(widget.user.id).once();
    if (snapshot.value != null) {
      setState(() {
        hayMensajes = true;
      });
      final data = snapshot.value;
      for (var entry in data.entries) {
        Message message = Message.fromJson(entry.value);
        setState(() {
          message.add(message);
        });
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        hayMensajes = false;
      });
    }
```

Anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, there are some active issues about FCM `onLaunch` callback with flutter. Some of them are still not fixed. One of the problems most people had to face was that `onLaunch` callback being called multiple times. I don't know why it happened, but as in your case, you can possibly get rid of the issue by some temporary fixes.

If the same screen is getting pushed over and over again, and glitching, you can pop the stack until it reaches the one you meant to open and set a condition to push navigator only if the new route is different from the old one. Using the named routes,

```dart
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName(routeName));

if (ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name != routeName) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, routeName);
}
```

I am not sure if that was the problem you asked, but I hope at least my answer helps somehow.

Comment: well,I just had to apply different logic, to bypass this issue, but it's kind of similar of your suggestion, so despite that I can't accept it like an answer, at the moment, I think it deserves an upvote.